# NetBeans Java project - Can’t see Libraries

Tags: libraries, java-12, netbeans-11

Disclaimer: I’m literally just learning from scratch how to program.  Using NetBeans 11 and JDK 12.

In order to follow a tutorial, I need to edit my Libraries settings.  However when I right click my project and click properties, there is no Libraries category in the tree.  I have done a bunch of searching and the results tell me that it just should be there by default.

How do I get it to appear???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I think I figured it out.  The tutorial was pointing me towards Libraries for importing dependencies, but it seems Maven doesn’t do things that way.  I had to import the dependencies to the relevant dependency folder in the tree.  This added it to the Pom file at the same time and now my imports work.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an option under Tool.

Tool -> Library

from there you can add libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I can't find the library so I can import SQL connector.

When I did import it from tools, the library could not appear in the project (as in the case of the video tutor) am using.